# Sorting 1D std::vector based Matrix based on columns

Tags: c++

I have a matrix class as follows (some parts are omitted for clarity):

```
template <typename T> class CMatrix{
protected:
   vector<T>* m_matrix;
public:
void SetCellValue(unsigned int row,unsigned int col,T value){ m_matrix->at(row*m_column+col)=value;}
T& GetCellValue(unsigned int row,unsigned int column) const{return m_matrix->at(row*m_column+column);}
```

I would like to have a function to sort the matrix based on a chosen column. Say if the matrix is:

2  3

1  4

After sorting based on 1st column it should look like:

1 4

2 3

Basically, since 1<2 we performed a row exchange. I know if `m_matrix` was a 2D vector, then `std::sort` would have worked. Is it possible to achieve sorting 1D std::vector based matrix, based on a chosen column.

The following worked very well for a 1D data type but could not tweak it to work with a matrix:

```
template <typename T> class Sorter{
    bool m_IsAscending;
public:
    Sorter() {m_IsAscending=true;}
    void SortAscending() {m_IsAscending=true;}
    void SortDescending(){m_IsAscending=false;}
    bool operator()(T i, T j){
        if(m_IsAscending) return (i<j); else return (i>j);
    }

};
```

Comment: Just curious as to why it's `vector<T>* m_matrix` instead of `vector<T> m_matrix`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: In order to be able to use an object construction like, say `CMatrix<double> m(2,3)`

Comment: You can construct the vector using the member initialization list of your constructor (`CMatrix::CMatrix(int a, int b) : m_matrix(a * b) {}`).  You don't need pointers.   As to your problem, I think you will need arrays of indices and use that in the sort, since index information as to where the matrix values are is not available in just a linear 1D representation of a 2D matrix.  It sounds tricky, but I don't see a way of doing this without these extra "helper" arrays that contain index information.

Comment: For example, an array of indices denoting where each row starts (i.e. using your example, `{0, 2}` would be the row start positions.  Also an array of indices indicating the position of each of the column values you're interested in sorting (again, using your example, `{0, 2}` would be the position of the columns to sort).  If an item is out of order, you would "swap rows" by swapping all items in the "rows" with each other.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I was actually thinking in alignment with you, such as grabbing one column and sorting it and tracking the index changes. Then creating a new matrix based on the new indexes. However, I felt it would be an expensive. However, so far it seems the only way.

Comment: It has been sometime to this post, but I have solved it by copying to a 2D `std::vector` and then sorting using `std::sort` and copying back to original vector. Maybe not the best solution but currently it works well and the code is readable and manageable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very easy. Remember that `std::sort` takes begin and end iterators. So all you have to do is split your matrix into parts and sort them individually:

```
for(long i = 0; i < num_of_columns; i++)
{
    std::sort(m_matrix->begin()+num_of_rows*i, m_matrix->begin()+num_of_rows*(i+1));
}
```

This will sort all individual columns independently. If you want to sort only one column, don't use a loop, and choose an `i` that is the column number you want to sort.

**Caveats:**
This will work if your matrix is flattened in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Otherwise, if it's in row-major, all you have to do is transpose the matrix, sort it with the code above, and transpose it back. I guess this is the only way to go if you want to avoid writing your own sorting function. **However**, if all you want is to sort a single column, and your matrix is in row-major order, then it's much cheaper to just copy that row to a new vector, sort it, and copy it back.

Btw, I don't understand why `m_matrix` is a pointer... that's very bad practice and is a welcome invitation to memory leaks (unless you're using a smart pointer to wrap it, such as `std::unique_ptr`).

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe I am not on the same page with you but even if I transpose and sort it, then it will only sort that particular column but will not sort the whole matrix based on that particular column. Am I right?

Comment: @macroland The code I provided will sort the whole matrix because it will go through all columns. If you just want to sort 1 column, then it's not worth transposing the whole matrix for that purpose, which is why I mentioned copying that column. Also If you often want to sort your columns this way, I recommend that you switch from row-major order to column-major order. That will simplify the job.

Comment: I still think we are not on the same page: Your code `individually and independently` sort all the columns, which is easy to do. However, what I want is say if you have 3 columns (0, 1,2) and you would like to sort 0th column; then 1 and 2 should `dependently` be row-exchanged based on 0th column. Your code sorts 0, 1 and 2 independently.

Comment: @macroland OK, you gotta help me out here. You can't just expect to copy my code and get your problem solved. I provided a few ideas that are sufficient to solve your problem. First, whether you want to sort the whole matrix or just one column is your decision. Second, I already suggested that you make your matrix in column-major, which will solve a part of the problem. Third, I already mentioned that **there's no way** to use `std::sort` if your matrix is in row-major order. The most difficult part is sorting, and I gave you that. Now all you have to do is use `std::swap` to swap elements.